# React Toggle Menu

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, event-handling, toggle

Im trying to build an Toggle right menu from this example : [how-to-build-a-sliding-menu-using-react-js"](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/how-to-build-a-sliding-menu-using-react-js-and-less-css-du107mpij)

the problem is React.createClass is deprecated so i have to change the code and it stop working i get the content but cant access the handlers cann anybody tell me which steps should i do to fix this issue! so if i click on my button i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

**ToggleMenu**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import localStyles from './ToggleMenu.scss';
import { themr } from 'react-css-themr';
import { Menu } from '../../components';
import { MenuItem } from '../../components';

@themr('ToggleMenu', localStyles)

export default class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {

  showRight() {
    this.refs.right.show();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showRight = this.showRight.bind(this);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Right Menu!</button>
      <Menu ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
      <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Menu**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
    };

    show() {
        this.setState({visible: true});
        document.addEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    hide() {
        this.setState({visible: false});
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menu">
                <div className={(this.state.visible ? "visible " : "") + this.props.alignment}>{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**MenuItem**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    navigate(hash) {
        window.location.hash = hash;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menu-item" onClick={this.navigate.bind(this, this.props.hash)}>{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the reference to `this.right`, you need to update the `showRight` method to something like this:

```
showRight() {
  this.right.show();
}
```

I'd also use an arrow function to avoid binding the function in the constructor.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default class ToggleMenu extends PureComponent {

  showRight = () => {
    this.right.show();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Right Menu!</button>
      <Menu ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
      <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And make sure to use `PureComponent` to avoid rendering the component when is not needed.

**Edit:**

The `Menu` class is not the react way, if you want to hide an element you should do something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    state = {
      visible: false,
    };

    show() {
      this.setState({ visible: true });
    }

    hide() {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }

    render() {
      const { visible } = this.state;

      return (
        <div className="menu">
          { 
            visible &&
              <div className={this.props.alignment}>{this.props.children}</div>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

If `visible === true` then the `div` will render, otherwise it won't. I removed the listeners, we don't do that in react, instead you need to define an `onClick` callback on the element that you want the user to click in order to hide the menu.

Comment: ok the error doesn't show anymore but , now nothing happend the menu still on the same place :/ but ur solution works , it jumps into show function :)

Comment: Probably the css? The whole `Menu` class looks weird, that's not the react way ;) I will update my answer to give you an idea

Comment: this would be the first right solution for an simple react toggle menu :D on the whole web :D found just ready developed npm packges. thank u so much